# Using a 5 pin button with Arduino Correctly

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, stepper-motor

I am trying to build a simple motor test sketch, currently, to test a NEMA 23 stepper motor and the DM542T stepper driver.

Here is the code, and I am having trouble figuring out how to properly wire the 5-lead button (+, -, Common, NO, NC)

Here is the code

```
// Pin numbers
const int buttonPin = 2;
const int directionPin = 8;
const int stepPin = 9;

// Other constants
const int NumSteps = 5000; // steps
const int Speed = 500; 

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(directionPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(directionPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin)) {
    // Move in one direction
    for (int distance = 0; distance < NumSteps; distance++) {
      digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(Speed);
      digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(Speed);
    }
   // Reverse direction
   digitalWrite(directionPin, !digitalRead(directionPin));
 }
  delay(5);
}
```

The button is a momentary button, so I am holding it in to simulate a latching button.

I have the buttons Common and Neg leads wired together, and connected to the Gnd pin on the Arduino (mega rev3)
I have the buttons Positive and the NC wired together and connected to pin 2.

Wiring that button in that manner, works fine in the button-controlled blink sketch, but is not working here (LED on the button doesn't light up and the motor test doesn't run).

Note: I am using a 5 lead momentary button as that what the project these motors will be for will be using.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you link to the buttons product page or datasheet? A simple button with 5 pins is not very common, so it is important how the button is  using the pins.

Comment: There is no datasheet for it. It is a standard 5 lead LED button with +,-,common,NC,NO. It worked fine when wired for the button controlled blink sketch with NO not connected, NC and + wired together to 5V and Common and - wired together to Gnd. The led on the button lights up and the led on the Mega lights up when you press the button

Comment: Oh, haven't seen, that it is an LED button. Can you please make a diagram which connections you really have? It is difficult to interpret with the text (and you have different wirings in the question and your comment). You can also use the builtin schematic editor of the question editor. Use a normal switch and an LED to simulate your 5 pin switch

Comment: first thought, do not connect the LED to the switch .... second thought, if the button works in a blink sketch, then use the working switch code in the motor sketch

Comment: You don't need a sketch to control the on-board LED. Just wire the + to 5V and the - to Gnd and the button will turn the on-board LED on/off. If it's an LED halo or lighted button combine the NO and + to 5V and the common and - to Gnd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button's pins are as follows:

- +: The LED's anode
- -: The LED's cathode
- C: The common pin of the switch
- NC: Normally Closed - is normally connected to the C pin until the button is pressed
- NO: Normally Open - is connected to the C pin when you press the button

So to use the button as a button the two pins you care about are C and NO. Use those pins (in any order) as you would any normal button with a pullup resistor (or the internal `INPUT_PULLUP` resistor).

To use the LED can be a little more tricky. Most of this style of button have the LED set up for 12V usage. While you *may* get a slight glow from it from 5V you would probably need to switch it with a transistor and power it from 12V to get it to light up properly. However your button may be rated differently and need a different voltage.

Comment: So, in this case which would you use as the signal and send to pin 2, the NO wire or the common? The other would go to Gnd I believe.

Comment: @dinotom It really doesn't matter. They are just lumps of metal that touch when you press the button, and since you're not using the NC pin which is which for C and NO makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: Yep, used the NO to pin 2 and the C to Gnd, serial monitor shows it changing. Onto the next problem, the button isn't turning the motors on. Connecting pos to 5V and Neg to Gnd does get the light on the button to flicker, weird it works as described before. Ill post a different question later if I can't figure that one out myself. Motors first.